# How can I uninstall part of a package?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management, uninstall

I have installed the [BSD games package](https://github.com/vattam/BSDGames). Many of the games are awful or broken, so I wish to uninstall some of them without uninstalling others. Is there an easy way to do that? Currently, I'm `sudo rm`ing them from `usr/share/applications/bsdgames` and `usr/games/`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To uninstall part of a package, your approach is correct: if you know you don’t (and won’t) need a file shipped in a package, you can delete it (after all, it’s your system). However if you leave it at that, the next time the package is upgraded, the deleted files will be restored (unless they are configuration files in `/etc`). To avoid that, you should tell `dpkg` that you don’t want the files you removed: add a configuration file in `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d`, with lines of the form

```
path-exclude=/path/to/foo
```

for every file you deleted.

As Marcus [says](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/761220/86440), this isn’t usually a great idea, and [the `dpkg` man page warns against it too](https://manpages.debian.org/dpkg/dpkg.1.en#path). But there are circumstances where it is appropriate; one common setup is to remove documentation shipped with packages, or man pages in languages which no one using your computer needs or wants. I have a `/etc/dpkg.cfg.d/locales` file containing

```
# Drop locales except English and French
path-exclude=/usr/share/locale/*
path-include=/usr/share/locale/en/*
path-include=/usr/share/locale/fr/*
path-include=/usr/share/locale/locale.alias

# Drop translated manpages except English and French
path-exclude=/usr/share/man/*
path-include=/usr/share/man/man[1-9]/*
path-include=/usr/share/man/en*/*
path-include=/usr/share/man/fr*/*
```

to avoid installing locale files and man pages in languages other than English or French.

Aggregate packages like `bsdgames` are another situation where file removals can be useful; the disk space savings are probably not worth it, but removing candidates from your path can be worthwhile (assuming you are the only user of your system).

Comment: `/etc/dpkg.cfg.d`: ohhhh! Learned something today!

Comment: one tiny nitpick: I don't think /usr/games ends up in the path, usually, to begin with.

Comment: @Marcus [on Debian](https://sources.debian.org/src/base-files/13/share/profile/) it does, and on Ubuntu as well (in `/etc/environment` there).

Comment: And Fedora & co. don’t have `/usr/games` on the path, but AFAIR they install games in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Is there a way to configure ignored files on a per-package basis ?

Comment: @aaaaaa not that I’m aware of.

Answer (score 15):

The point of packaging is that the packages are integral units.

So, there's no *easy* way to do that, without breaking the packaging itself. You usually don't want to do that.

> Currently, I'm sudo rming them from usr/share/applications/bsdgames and usr/games/.

You especially don't want to do that: the next software/distro update / rebuild will re-establish these, and also, generally, stay the hell away from things that your system installed using `apt`.

Quite honestly, though: The whole package needs a total of 3.7 MB of space. That is roughly the same amount of data you use when you opened this very page. Just ignore the games you don't like, there's no measurable downside to you – 3.7 MB is *nothing* on a machine that runs ubuntu.

Comment: Nice answer - I only want to mention it's possible OP wants to remove those games to remove the clutter rather than the size of the file i.e. when you search for "snak" in an application launcher the game "snake" might come up even though it's broken - or the games are showing up in some other part of the UI..

Comment: That's fair. A rather helpful and relatively lazy way of course would be submitting a bug report to the distro that says "snake's broken, please remove", and waiting a few days.